# Angular2 custom tooltip on icon click

Tags: html, angular, tooltip

I want to show a tooltip when i click an icon, not by hovering on it.

```
<a title="Tooltip">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
```

I also want to be able to customize to the tooltip with some classes like:

```
<div class="a-tooltip a-tooltip--top-right">
  This is my tooltip text!
</div>
```

**My try:**

```
<a (click)="tooltip.toggle()"
   #tooltip="matTooltip"
   matTooltip="test"
   aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
   <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
```

This does however not show a tooltip on clicking.
In app.module.ts i have:

```
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        MatTooltipModule 
    ]
})
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you failing?

Comment: @emkay see update.

Answer (score 4):

By default mat-tooltip is designed for mouse hover. If, you want to disable that use the following code :

```
<span matTooltip="Tooltip!" 
  (mouseenter)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()" 
  (mouseleave)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()"
  #tooltip="matTooltip" (click)="tooltip.toggle()">Test</span>
```

Comment: With this, I can make an Icon clickable. However, the tooltip is not show near the clicked element, but a mat-tooltip-component is placed at the bottom of my page, below the footer...

Comment: Please provide an example.